# Align subscribe form

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align the subscribe form just beneath the featured image. I used a subscribe form I found on codepen.io and I'm not sure how to position this form. I'm adding the html and css. If anyone can help me with this I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

**Current Output:**

```css
 #mc_embed_signup {
   background: none;
   font: 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   margin: 500px;
   padding: 0;
 }
 .email_capture--wrapper {
   max-width: 600px;
   display: block;
   margin: 5% -70px;
   padding: 0 15px;
 }
 .mailchimp {
   width: 100%;
 }
 .mailchimp input[type="email"] {
   background: #f5f5f5;
   height: 55px;
   padding: 18px 20px;
   font-size: 20px;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   color: #444;
   float: left;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
   border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 }
 .mailchimp input[type="submit"] {
   font-size: 18px;
   height: 55px;
   float: left;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
   -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
   border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
 }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .mailchimp .form-group > input[type="email"] {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  }
  .mailchimp .form-group > input[type="submit"] {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pull-right">
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top pull-right">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
      <link href="..." rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
</div>
<!--end of pull-right -->

<div id="mc_embed_signup">
  <form action="..." method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
      <label for="mce-EMAIL"></label>
      <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
      <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
      <div id="signup">
        <input type="text" name="..." tabindex="-1" value="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see your image!

Comment: You have to provide working example of this.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I usually use cssdesk, codepen.io or just upload to the server, but those aren't an option right now. I thought the image would be sufficient.

Comment: You can create a Codepen and attach the link here,

Comment: you can use jsfiddle

Comment: [link] (http://codepen.io/erodriguez2385/pen/pjKbor)

Comment: @EricaRodriguez that CodePen doesn't want to load for me :(